# Why System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo has unreachable code?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

New .NET4.5 API has the following logic in IntrospectionExtensions class

```
public static TypeInfo GetTypeInfo(this Type type)
{
  if (type == (Type) null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
  IReflectableType reflectableType = (IReflectableType) type;
  if (reflectableType == null) 
    return (TypeInfo) null; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE!
  else
    return reflectableType.GetTypeInfo();
}
```

Why this method has unreachable code? Is this a bug or done intentionally?

Comment: Is this the output of some decompiler? Maybe the original source code was `IReflectableType reflectableType = type as IReflectableType;` and the decompiler got it wrong.

Comment: IL DASM shows (  IL_0015:  castclass  System.Reflection.IReflectableType) not (isinst), so there is a strict cast.

Answer (score 6):

The confusion is caused by the `==` operator defined on the `Type` class.

If you look at the IL, you will see the operator is called instead of `ReferenceEquals`.

```
L_0002: call bool System.Type::op_Equality(class System.Type, class System.Type)
```

So the code is in fact reachable :)

Comment: So, as I understand 

System.Type::op_Equality(class System.Type, class System.Type)

can return false iven if type is NULL. Because Type class has no explicit cast operators and code

if (reflectableType == null)
    {return (TypeInfo)null; // <<< this}

will be reachable only if type is NULL.

Comment: `Type::op_Equality` and the null check is not comparable, so it is irrelevant what `Type::op_Equality` can return. Obviously, it has some funky semantics, but I dont know them off the top of my head ;p